# Does value of "Today" updates daily on sharepoint 2013 WF?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, designer-workflow, email

i need to build a custom email reminder workflow which uses "Today" value to calculate a date and to perform action action based on that,so i just wanted to know whether "Today" will be automatically updated on my WF ?

Answer (score 0):

This will update whenever your workflow starts or continues.
If you put this value in a variable you will be able to save the today date for long running workflows (e.g. approval WF over several days/weeks).

Comment: actually i need to calculate a date using "Today" and will store it on some WF variable and have to send a reminder mail on that particular stored date automatically,is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will update automatically every day. But you need to Run your workflow in loop.

Comment: can you please elaborate by sharing a sample workflow

Comment: Yes Sure, Here is how you can write your Workflow : 
https://jenniferannmason.com/2014/02/24/office365-sharepoint-2013-create-a-weekly-reminder-workflow/

Comment: have you tried this?